# Meteor reactive computation not triggered on collection.update()

Tags: javascript, canvas, meteor, fabricjs

I've defined a Meteor Collection which stores paths to allow for a shared drawing canvas:

```
CanvasPaths = new Meteor.Collection("canvasPaths");
```

I redraw the canvas in an autorun block:

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
    var paths = CanvasPaths.find().fetch();
    //some stuff happens
}
```

Adding paths to the collection with collection.insert() triggers this autorun block to run again as the computation is invalidated:

```
CanvasPaths.insert({
    path: collectionPath
});
```

However when I update a path already in the collection the computation is not invalidated and the autorun function does not rerun:

```
CanvasPaths.update(id, {
    $set: {
        path: getPathObjectForCollection(this)
    }
});
```

Surely updating the collection invalidates any computations in reactive blocks that use that collection?
How can I make the function in the autorun block rerun on all clients?

**EDIT**

In response to Junle Li's comment:
I added

```
console.log(CanvasPaths.findOne(id).path); //exisiting record
console.log(getPathObjectForCollection(this)); //what we are updating to
```

just before the CanvasPaths.update call, this gives the result:
[image]

So as you can see, positionLeft and positionTop's values have changed so surely the Autorun block should be called.

Comment: Please debug to ensure that your `getPathObjectForCollection(this)` returned value is different from the existing value. If the original value and the new value is the same. Autorun will not be triggered.

Comment: I've updated the question with this debug info, thanks

Comment: The update is rendered after the page is refreshed on other clients but the canvas is not updated reactively.  The canvas does however update reactively when new paths are inserted into the collection.

Comment: I test on my own Meteor project, it works fine. Maybe you can debug using `CanvasPaths.update(id, {...}, function(err, id) { //debug here }` callback.

Comment: Just tried this, the err is undefined so the update is completing properly.  As I mentioned the canvas does update properly with the pushed updates on a page refresh so the data is reaching the database properly, it's just not causing a reactive update.

Comment: Can you check whether the computation is actually invalidated? https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#user-content-how-can-i-tell-why-my-code-is-getting-re-run

Comment: I've just realised a possible cause of the error, I have a feeling the autorun block is running but due to some drawing optimisations I put in to prevent already rendered paths being rerendered, I don't think the new path position is being drawn as the program sees it as already having been drawn so doesn't attempt to redraw it.  Hence, the path is not replaced with the path in the new position.  I'll check this and confirm with an answer when I have time if this is the case.  Thanks all for your help in helping with the debugging process though.

Comment: If I were you I would do it with SVG instead of drawing on canvas. You wouldn't need any autorun blocks since SVG elements in templates are "natively" supported by Blaze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out update was triggering the autorun after all (as it should do).

The code I wanted to be executing in the autorun wasn't executing due to the if statement it was contained in evaluating to false for unrelated reasons.

In future, It's best to have a `console.log("auto run executed");` at the beginning of the autorun block.  Then you'll instantly know if an autorun is being triggered or not under whatever conditions.